# EA Name a Lifeline

Tags: c#, api, automation, uml, enterprise-architect

I would like to give a lifeline the name of the class or actor its belongs to as well as it ihas been created.

This can avoid confusion when elements are deleted by other users or by mistake.

On the `PreNewDiagramObject` and `PreNewElement` events I would like to check if the element is a lifline, and in case it is- to name it.

Is it possible using EA API? or may there are some manual settings that perform it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use **EA_OnPostNewElement**. The **EA_OnPre~** events are generally only used if you want to prevent creation whereas the **EA_OnPost~** events are used to modify something after it has been created.

Comment: Thanks for the guiding re the correct event. Do you know how can I set the name of the lifeline to its class?